# ubuntu 14.04 no icons

Tags: 14.04

I've installed ubuntu 14.04 on vmware workstation, there are no icons on desktop.

I've tried:

1. `startx`
2. `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`

> command line option 'g' [from -get] is not known.

why known??

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may have downloaded the server version instead of the desktop.  Check the file name and make sure it has desktop in the name, something like this - ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop.iso.